# Generating autorest client from different OpenAPI versions

Tags: .net, typescript, swagger, openapi, autorest

I'm looking into generating a Typescript client from our .NET API, I landed on using [Autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.typescript) since it's built with Node (Which I'm familiar with). I also know of Swashbuckle but I'm not familiar with Java.

Our API is versioned, most endpoints are on `V1` (e.g. `/v1/users`), but certain endpoints have been updated and are now prefixed by `V2` (e.g. `/v2/users`).

Swagger/OpenAPI only lists either:

- http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json
- http://localhost:5000/swagger/v2/swagger.json

Neither of these JSON files contains all endpoints, they would need to be unified into a single file to have all endpoints availaible.

How do I make Autorest generate clients for both of these at the same time? Generating one then the other overwrites the first so I can't seem to get them to exist at the same time.

What should I do here? Is it the backend's responsibility to make the V2 page list all endpoints from V1? Is there a way to get Autorest to generate both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I realised you can either pass multiple `--input-file` arguments via CLI or you can pass an array to the yaml config:

```
input-file:
  [
    http://192.168.125.44:4999/swagger/v1/swagger.json,
    http://192.168.125.44:4999/swagger/v2/swagger.json,
  ]
```